# React js only on part of the app?

Tags: reactjs

I want to make only `/projects` conrolled by React.

React handles URLs among these endpoints:

```
/projects
/projects/123
/projects/123/edit
/projects?k=v&k2=v2
...
```

Clicking a link outside `/projects` loads everything from scratch.

---

**Question 1**:How do I make React redraw the entire page? How to make react render `/projects` from `/projects/123`? It has to re-render from the root right?

**Question 2**: How do I distinguish clicks between say, `<a href="/projects/something">` and `<a href="/settings/something">` with the former making React pushState and the latter allowing the browser load it?

Doing this in JQuery is familiar to me, listening to clicks on `<a ..>` elements. Should I continue to do it this way? Not all the links will be rendered by React, user messages are an example.

**Question 3**: I have server API endpoints in `/projects`, `/projects/123` etc. What do I serve when the browser (not XHR) hits each endpoint? I guess I must code **each** endpoint to serve the app if accessed by a browser. Or is there a way to avoid this redundancy?

Comment: You should use `react-router` for handling routes.

Comment: @limelights Im watching the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XZfvW1a8Xac), and you could post an actual answer

Comment: Thanks but it felt more like a comment worthy answer! :)